# Assigning a variant to a combobox and vice-versa

Tags: vba, combobox, variant

I am trying to assign a variant the "value" of a combobox in a userform in order to store the list so that I can re-assign the "Value" of the variant to the combobox when initializing the userform.

Here is the code I am using to assign my variant the List value of the combobox before the userform is closed:

```
Dim S()
Private Sub ExitButton_Click()
ReDim S(1 To NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.ListCount)
S = NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.List
Unload Me
End Sub
```

I then use this set of code in a separate sub to initialize the combobox upon opening the userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.List = S

End Sub
```

Note that `Dim S()` has been declared as a global variable. I get the following error message:

> "Run-error '380':
>
> Could not set the list property. Invalid property value."

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, how do you create the code blocks like that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Not sure but maybe the ```S``` is Empty at the beginning? And it is not possible to assign ```Empty``` to ```List```? Add a check like ```If Not IsEmpty(S) Then NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.List = S```.

Comment: @dee - It was indeed empty in the beginning. The previous code was inserted into the useform code and therefor 'S()' was being cleared each time the macro ended. I solved this by performing the following code in a separate module and calling the first sub when I open the userform and the second when once I close the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim ArrRep() As Variant

Public Sub PopulateCombos()

NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.List = ArrRep

End Sub

Public Sub SaveCombos()

ReDim ArrRep(1 To NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.ListCount)
ArrRep = NewRecordUserForm.RepCombo.List

End Sub
```

I called the first sub upon opening the userform and the second just before it closes. Worked!